# Unable to delete files from my Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Currently working with a Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie. When I try to move files from home to my wastebasket, I get error:

`Unable to create wastebasket dir /home/pi/.local/share/Trash: No space left on device`

The lack of space on my device is why I was trying to delete things. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What size is your SD card? What is the output of df -h? Please add this info to your question not in a comment.

Comment: I will update on Sunday, do not have access to the Pi right now.

Answer (score 1):

try using command line to delete stuff

```
sudo rm filename.ext
```

or

```
sudo rm -r directoryname
```

to delete a directory with stuff in it

Comment: This should probably work. I'm away from the Pi right now but will try it later, thanks

Comment: How does this address the underlying issue - that he is out of space on the card/partition. This may work because Raspbian reserves some space for the root user when the disk is otherwise full.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, it addresses the issue by freeing up space.  `rm` actually deletes files, where dragging them to the trash just moves them around.

Comment: Unless the file is huge this is like using a dixie cup to empty a swimming pool.

Comment: I believe that there are some large files I could get rid of, I wound up downloading multiple versions of Python3 in my attempts to get pip to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you already haven't done so, You can resize your filesystem to expand to fill the whole SD card using [`raspi-config`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md).

Answer (score 0):

It s always recommended to Expand the file system after initial installation. Here is the link for the Same https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md

In your case as you are already having space issues, below is the link ( the article is on updating / upgrade of Raspbian), but reading - **RUNNING OUT OF SPACE** section will help you resolve your problem

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md

Hope this helps.